# How can I delete files in a directory which are copied from another directory?

Tags: ant

I have two directories, say, A and B. A has several files: a1, a2, a3. B also has several files: b1, b2.
First, I use the following ant tasks to copy all the files from B to A.

```
<copy todir="A" verbose="true">
    <fileset dir="B" includes="*"/>
</copy>
```

Then I want to undo the steps, i.e. delete the files in A which are copied from B, namely b1 and b2. How can I achieve the goals?

NOTE: the file names in the example are just used for us to understand the problem. I do not know the exact file names in the two directories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a Selector to populate the FileSet of those files you want to delete. Try the [Present Selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#presentselect). Here's a target to complement your example:

```
<target name="copy" >
<copy todir="A" verbose="true">
    <fileset dir="B" includes="*"/>
</copy>
</target>

<target name="uncopy" >
<delete verbose="true">
    <fileset dir="A" >
        <present present="both" targetdir="B"/>
    </fileset>
</delete>
</target>
```

Comment: Glad to help! The usual practice is to accept the answer by ticking it (see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). It helps others find the answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

While I've never used ant before, presumably the files copied from A would have current timestamp. If you delete all files from B with that timestamp, you should only get the A files, just watch out for the problem linux has. Namely, multiple timestamps for different things, and if you copy you change one but not the others.

If that won't work, perhaps you can set the owner of the files in A to be a special owner before you copy them. Then delete all of that owner's files out of B. Whatever solution you use will hinge on the fact that some piece of data differentiates your A files from your B files, either name or owner or timestamp. If there is no consistent difference, you need to make one.

Comment: Well, distinguishing the files from A and B by timestamp will not work if I changed the files later. I want to delete the files from B by name. Thank you, anyway.